# Using try...catch with 2 sequential API calls

Tags: fetch, try-catch, throw

Can you tell me if this is valid syntax please (it's written as a method),

```
async apiCalls () {
  try{
    const firstCall = await fetch (...);
    if(firstCall.ok) {
      ...
    } else {
      throw new Error('First call didn't work');
    };
    
    const secondCall = await fetch (...);
    if(secondCall.ok) {
      ...
      return;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Second call didn't work');
    };

  } catch (error) {
    alert(error)
  };
}
```

Perhaps the first api call could be to get a user ID and the second could be to post some information with the ID.  Also, if "throw" is executed, is the next line executed after that the catch(error)?  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? You will then easily see whether it works or not. You have superfluous empty statements caused by stray `;`s after your `if` and `try` blocks by the way.

Comment: @CherryDT I didn't know how I could simulate a bad response to the fetch call, but I suppose I could just put a ```!``` in front of ```response.ok``` and see what happens. By the way, I don't think there's anything wrong with my use of ```;```.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes it works the way I wanted it to. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What's wrong with your use of `;` is that blocks don't need a `;` following them, syntactically that would be adding an additional empty statement. It is _either_ a single statement followed by `;` _or_ a block, but the block doesn't get a `;` after the `}`. About how to simulate: If this is in the frontend, you can also use your browser devtools to simulate failed requests, slow networks, etc., these are all facilities provided by modern browsers built-in.

Comment: That's interesting, I will do further research into both points. Thanks a lot.